# How to trigger a flip effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code  to create a flip image where I want the image to show a flip effect when user `click` it.

```js
let img = document.querySelector('img')
let div;
let click = 0;
   img.onclick=function(){
   console.log(click)
   if(click %2 ==0){
  div = document.createElement('div')   
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  div.className = 'flip'
    div.textContent= 'Wikipedia'
  img.style.display = 'none'
  }else{
  img.style.display = 'revert'
  div.remove()
  }
  click++
}
```

```css
@keyframes fliping{
from{
transform: rotateY(0deg);
}to{
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
}
img{
width:100px;
height:70px;
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:20px;
text-align:center;
line-height:70px;
}
.flip{
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:20px;
width:100px;
height:70px;
background:grey;
 animation-name: fliping;
   animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://blogs.stthomas.edu/english/files/2016/04/Wikipedia-Logo.jpg'>
```

I try to use `keyframe` to do that. However, there are two problems with my code:

The text will flip as the element flips.

I am unable to click the `img` again to flip back since I make the `img` tag to become `display:none`.

Could anyone tell me how could I solve the problem or provide me a better solution to trigger a flip effect?

Thanks for any responds!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_flip_image2 Does this help?

Comment: @IPSDSILVA  The OP is asking for something else and not the one of which the link you have shared

Answer (score 2):

You should use opacity instead of display.

```js
let img = document.querySelector('img')
let div;
let click = 0;
   img.onclick=function(){
   console.log(click)
   if(click %2 ==0){
  div = document.createElement('div')   
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  div.className = 'flip'
    div.textContent= 'Wikipedia'
  img.style.opacity = '0'
  }else{
  img.style.opacity = '100'
  div.remove()
  }
  click++
}
```

```css
@keyframes fliping{
from{
transform: rotateY(0deg);
}to{
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
}
img{
width:100px;
height:70px;
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:20px;
text-align:center;
line-height:70px;
z-index: 2;
}
.flip{
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:20px;
width:100px;
height:70px;
background:grey;
 animation-name: fliping;
   animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://blogs.stthomas.edu/english/files/2016/04/Wikipedia-Logo.jpg'>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But just wonder is there way to solve the text flip as the element flip problem?